# Can I use Postfix with a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a nested list Data set with mostly numbers, there are a few elements that occur as strings that I want to convert to a number. By postfixing `ToExpression` I get the desired result, however it also evaluates strings that I use as blanks, they are always the same string, can I exclude them from the `ToExpression`?

So I have data like this but much larger

```
Dataset1 = {{1,2,3,4} 3,"4",5}, {1,2,3,4} 3,"#N/A",5}}

Dataset1 = Dataset1//ToExpression
```

So this will turn "4" into 4 but it will also make "#N/A" into #N÷A

I've tried postfixing this, but that doesn't work:

```
ConvertStringNumbers[x_] := If[ x != "#N/A", ToExpression[x], x]

Dataset1 = Dataset1//ConvertStringNumbers
```

Comment: Something like: `Dataset1 /. s_String?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]) :> ToExpression[s]`?

Comment: Thanks this works, I think making it a command will suit me better.